# How to connect Jenkins from on-premises environment to AWS Ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, aws-ec2-instance-connect

I Am trying to connect My On-premises Jenkins to AWS Ec2 via SSH Connection. But I am Unable to connect.

It is getting error while checking Connection As shown below

[Jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx4ed.png)

Can anyone tell How to connect my On-premises Jenkins to AWS Ec2 instance?

Comment: Does the security group where your instance is has the port 22 open? Is your EC2 in a public subnet? What if your try from your pc?

Comment: yes port 22 is open and ec2 is in public subnet. Our's is secure environment and we are using msjenkins

Comment: you followed this? https://www.thesunflowerlab.com/blog/jenkins-aws-ec2-instance-ssh/
Are you sure your on-premises is able to make outbound connection on port 22?